# CSS Hover, Can't change link color

Tags: html, css, hover

Ive looked around on many other answers, tried and failed miserably.

I am trying to keep the font color in both the header and footer white whist when hovering it changes to pink... So The hover works beautifully but i just cant get the font colour to stay white in either the header or footer.

There are other links that also hover pink, but the font stays black which is what i want.

This is probably an easy fix, but i am still learning :)

Website: http://www.growinhealth.org.uk

Thank you :)

Comment: You should post the HTML and CSS you're having problems with in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Remove:

```
#header .a:hover{
    color:#d80073
}
```

... and add the following:

```
#footer a:hover, #header a:hover  {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Also your HTML Markup is malformed. Take a look at:
http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.growinhealth.org.uk%2F

Comment: Ill check out the link... 
I think you've misunderstood, my fault... I need the Link colour white and the hover to be pink.

Like on the header the font colour is a bluish colour, I want it to be white, but am struggling to change it to white

Answer (score 0):

a:hover { color: #D80073;} in style.css @ 239 line number is making mouseover color pink

Add following css

```
#header a:hover,#footer a:hover{color:#fff}
```

and this will not change footer links white.

Answer (score 0):

Your links look like this:

```
<a target="_blank" href:="http://www.altonhousehotel.com"><u>www.altonhousehotel.com </u></a>
```

But they should look like this:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.altonhousehotel.com"><u>www.altonhousehotel.com</u></a>
```

There's a colon in you href links that shouldn't be there. This will result in links being presented like text.

Also, in your css file you have this:

```
#header .a:link {
    color: white;
}
```

You  want to change it to this:

```
#header a:link {
    color: white;
}
```

The dot means you target the class named `a` (you don't have any). Without the dot you'll target the elements `a`.

Comment: Thank you for spotting that :)

Comment: It has yes, however i've managed to get the footer how i want it - white with a pink hover, but it wont do the same for the header? 
Thanks for spotting these things :)